# How to use Bootstrap Icon Picker in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I am creating a list item that generated by jQuery script. I would like to have each list item with an icon chosen from font awesome.

My JS script to create a list and my HTML markup are as below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var menuID = 0;
        var itemCount = 1;

        $('.add-new-id').click(function() {
            menuID = $('.menu-id').val();
            $('.menu-id, .add-new-id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            return false;
        });
        $('#new-parent').submit(function() {
            var newParent = $('input.new-parent').val();
            $('ol.example:last').append('<li>' + newParent + '<button class="btn btn-default" role="iconpicker"></button></li>');
            itemCount++;
            $('input.new-parent').val('');
            return false;
        });


        $('body').on('click', 'button[role="iconpicker"]', function() {
            $(this).iconpicker();
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/elusive-icons-2.0.0/css/elusive-icons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/ionicons-1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/map-icons-2.1.0/css/map-icons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/material-design-1.1.1/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/octicons-2.1.2/css/octicons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/typicons-2.0.6/css/typicons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/icon-fonts/weather-icons-1.2.0/css/weather-icons.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker/css/bootstrap-iconpicker.min.css"/>
      <title>Menu</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form action="" id="new-parent">
              <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control new-parent" placeholder="Add parent menu">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default add-new-parent" type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <h4>Available Forms:</h4>
            <ol class="example">
            </ol>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<!-- Icon picker script-->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/iconset/iconset-all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker-1.7.0/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/bootstrap-iconpicker.js"></script>
<!-- end script-->
    </body>

    </html>
```

For each list item icon, I would like to use Bootstrap-Iconpicker from [this site](https://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/). However, it does not work fine for each generated list item as you can see from screen shot and on my site.

**Popup Icon Picker**

[image]

By clicking on left and right arrow, or typing in text box, it does not work at all.

Please kindly test it on my [demo site](http://menubuilder.byethost16.com/?i=1):

I could not find to any way to figure it out.
Please kindly help, your suggestion and solution are very much appreciate, thanks.